# Custom NSTextFieldCell draws text differently

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nstextfieldcell

I have view-based NSTableView with 2 text columns.

First column uses custom NSTextFieldCell. Second column uses the default cell.

Here's the custom cell code:

```
class CustomTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {
    // don't do anything, just call the super implementation
    override func drawInterior(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView) {
        super.drawInterior(withFrame: cellFrame, in: controlView)
    }
}
```

Somehow the text fields in the custom (first) column look differently (thinner?).
Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Jaw.png) (Sierra).

Not sure what's going on, may be custom implementation uses different antialiasing settings.

What am I missing there? Thank you in advance.

*edit: mentioned view-based NSTableView*

Comment: Similar question: [drawTitle:withFrame:inView Changes font looks when it shouldn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640285/drawtitlewithframeinview-changes-font-looks-when-it-shouldnt).

Comment: @Willeke Thanks. Looks like there's still no solution :(

Comment: I created test project based on your description and it renders fine: https://github.com/emankovski/TableRendersFine So maybe something else you forgot to mention?

Comment: @EugeneMankovski Sorry, I didn't mention that I use View-Based NSTableView. However I added a much simpler case with just 2 textfields to your project: https://github.com/DanPristupov/TableRendersFine. There's a slight difference between the textfields: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/vty1w647j840kkq/2017-01-24%20at%2008.08.png

Comment: Text field still relies on its cell in rendering a lot. Maybe create custom NSTextFieldCell if you need any custom drawing?

Comment: @EugeneMankovski I just updated the example (https://github.com/DanPristupov/TableRendersFine) to show that custom NSTextFieldCell also draws itself incorrectly. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yea I tried different things and nothing helps. Feels like a Cocoa bug. I suspect someone from Apple dev team could explain what is going on. My guess is that something has to be set for proper superclass rendering...

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that bug still exists today. Overriding `NSTextField.draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)` or `NSTextFieldCell.draw(withFrame cellFrame: NSRect, in controlView: NSView)` and simply calling `super` is enough to reproduce this behavior.

As a workaround, set `textField.drawsBackground = false`, place your text field into an `NSBox` or custom `NSView` and handle your drawing there.